# Is there a better way to use onLogs and getTransaction to be able to receive data real-time?

Tags: web3.js, js

Right now I am using the [onLogs](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#logssubscribe) stream to subscribe to a wallet.

I check the logs and when is the type of tx I need I use the [getTransaction](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettransaction) to be able to get more info about the tx.

Is there a better way to this? In order to not have to call getTransaction everytime to get more in-deep info?

Answer (score 1):

You've done the best thing.  The only other option is to subscribe to all block updates and pick out the transactions that interest you, but I think your solution is better.